# C# Sending ENTER to div in WebView using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, webview

I'm trying to create a simple program in C# that writes message in a field at a website and then sends enter. I can type messages without any problem with the method below but sending it doesn't seem to work. I found a way that works in web browser's console but in C# it returns:

```
System.Exception: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020101'
```

My code is:

```
public async void SendEnter() {
    await currentView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new[] {
        "var ev = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');" +
        "ev.initKeyEvent('keydown', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 13, 0);" +
        "document.getElementById(\"box-interface-input\").dispatchEvent(ev);"
    });
}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this doesn't work?

PS: I'm not using submit() since it's not a standard form and it doesn't work in browser.

Comment: Although I don't see anything immediately wrong with you code, have you tried to debug your WebView (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn715902.aspx)? What is the actual error inside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error message indicates a syntax error in the javascript.

While I don't know the exact environment you're developing on, the [Dottoro entry for `initKeyEvent`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljbwbehw.php) indicates that only Firefox supports this method, whereas the other browsers implemented `initKeyboardEvent` instead. The [MDN entry for `initKeyEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyEvent) expands on this a little to say that it is only valid for Gecko-based browsers.

MDN also says that both it and [`initKeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/initKeyboardEvent) are deprecated, and it should not be used as it is not cross-browser compatible, instead pointing to [the `KeyboardEvent` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) as the modern, cross-browser way to raise this type of event.

This may not be a problem in your particular use case, I really don't know. But everything else in your code looks fine to me, and in the absence of any other errors, `initKeyEvent` is where I'd start looking.